# Which adjective can describe my meaning?

Tags: adjectives

I want to say "during my education, I attended courses which were (**applicable/ workable/practical**), and hands-on experience in my internship"
Or, instead of them, which adjective can I use that better convey my meaning? or another well-formed sentence?

Comment: You learn facts, but you _take_ courses. If you use _applicable_ you need to say what the courses _applied to_. Do you mean you took the _appropriate_ courses for your chosen career?

Comment: @KateBunting do you mean that I write "during my education, I took appropriate courses and hands-on experience in my internship"?

Comment: I said '**the** appropriate courses'. That would be OK if you have already stated what the courses were appropriate for. Also, you _had_ or _received_ experience.

Comment: You haven't said what meaning you're trying to convey. What meaning is it? Currently, all we have is two words which you've considered and rejected. But we don't know why you considered them in the first place, or why you rejected them.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonBassford, I want to say that the courses that I passes were useful and I could use them directly in my career and industry without learning anything more (I cannot remember its word clearly but I think it was something like in-service learning)

Comment: @Alan Something like **sufficient**? (That only addresses the last part of your requirement though.)